# Cant click element [selenium]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have tried all the ways to locate elements on seleniums documentation but i can't figure it out. Any help appreciated.

```
def protonmail_signup():
    browser.get('https://protonmail.com/signup')
    time.sleep(random.randint(10,15))
    free_acc = browser.find_element_by_class_name('panel-heading').click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,3))
    free_elem = browser.find_element_by_id('freePlan').click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(20,25))
    email_elem = browser.find_element_by_id('username').click()
```

Everything works fine except for:

```
email_elem = browser.find_element_by_id('username').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `username` is inside an `iframe` element. You will need to switch to the `iframe`, then enter username text:

```
# save main frame context so we can switch back later
main_frame = driver.current_window_handle

# Get the first iframe -- there are two
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form']")[0]

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# enter email
email_elem = browser.find_element_by_id('username').click()
```

Then, you'll need to switch back to the main frame to enter password:

```
# switch back to main frame
driver.switch_to_window(main_frame)

#enter password next
```

As mentioned in my comment, there are two nested `iframe` elements. The first one `[0]` will get you the `iframe` containing the username. The second one, you will need to switch to so you can click `Create Account`.

```
second_iframe = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form']")[1]

driver.switch_to.frame(second_iframe)

# click Create Account button
```